# npm install throws node_modules/@angular/cli error in angular

Tags: angular

when I try to run my solution, I came across many errors in angular. Not sure where and what I am doing wrong.
Any suggestions would be very helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

a couple of versions ago, npm started automatically checking for peer deps. Use the above command to workaround that.